# What does scrambling communication channels do?

Tags: star-trek

In Star Trek what does it mean to "***scramble communication channels***"? It seems to be done as some form of security measure.

Additionally, what does it mean when they specify a word after giving the order, for example "Scrambler code Riker1". Is that like the password?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrambler

Comment: My understanding was that it was a sort of encryption for the messaging

Comment: As Kreiri points out, scrambling is a real thing, and questions about real things are off-topic for SFF.SE.

Comment: Disagree with it being off-topic. Question is being asked within the context of 'Star Trek'.  Per the site - 'Questions seeking scientific solutions or explanations are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction'.

Comment: I"m with @Stan. Mind you, I still don't think this is a very good question, but it is still within the rules.

Comment: If I asked what Earl Grey was, would that be off-topic?

Comment: If you're talking about the tea, then yes, because that is not an essential part of the *Science Fiction* aspect

Answer (score 5):

Communication scrambling is a thing that already exists.  Essentially it is a way to ensure the privacy of data,voice, or video transmissions.  In Star Trek much like in the real world, they would use this to protect their transmissions of sensitive or private information.

From the Answers page for Communication scrambling.

http://www.answers.com/topic/communications-scrambling

> Analog voice-scrambling methods typically involve splitting the voice
>   frequency spectrum into a number of sections by means of a filter bank
>   and then shifting or reversing the sections for transmission in a
>   manner determined by switch settings similar to those of a combination
>   lock; the reverse process takes places at the receive end. Digital
>   methods first convert the analog voice to digital form and then
>   scramble or encrypt the digital voice data by one of the methods
>   discussed below. See also Analog-to-digital converter; Electric
>   filter.
>
> A simple data-scrambling method involves the addition of a
>   pseudorandom number sequence to the data at the transmit end. Devices
>   using this method are known as stream ciphers. A second method
>   partitions the data into blocks. Data within a block may be permutated
>   bit by bit or substituted by some other data in a manner determined by
>   the switch setting, which is often called a key. Devices using this
>   method are known as block ciphers. See also Cryptography.
>
> Typical video scrambling devices used for cable television
>   applications involve modifying the amplitude or polarity of the
>   synchronization signals, thereby preventing the normal receiver from
>   detecting the synchronization signals. A more sophisticated technique,
>   used in satellite transmission, introduces a random delay to the
>   active video signal on a line-by-line basis. An even more advanced
>   technique called cut-and-rotate has been proposed. Video signals can
>   also be digitized by a number of coding techniques and then scrambled
>   by any of the data-scrambling techniques discussed above to achieve
>   high security. See also Closed-circuit television.
>
> Read more:
>   http://www.answers.com/topic/communications-scrambling#ixzz2wE3fZ9vc

Obviously in Star Trek they would use more advanced means to scramble their information but generally it just is a way of encrypting information.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to find **four** instances of communications being intentionally "*scrambled*". The effects (and intentions) are listed below;

- In TNG : "[Best of Both Worlds, Part II](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Best_of_Both_Worlds,_Part_II_%28episode%29)", the reason is relatively mundane; **to prevent the Borg from using Picard's knowledge of Federation communications systems to intercept their messages**. The reason for the "code" isn't explained, but I think we can assume it's something to do with the pattern used to encrypt the communications, something like a [public key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

> **RIKER :** *Reset subspace communications to scrambler code Riker One…*
>   **GLEASON :** *Scrambler code Riker One, acknowledged.*

- In TNG "[Menage a Troi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/M%C3%A9nage_%C3%A0_Troi_%28episode%29)", Data informs Picard that the Ferenghi use scrambling **to prevent the identification of their ships**:

> **DATA :** *Ferengi transmissions are routinely scrambled and encoded, sir. Without breaking the code, we will be unable to identify any
>   specific Ferengi vessel.*

- In TOS : "[Mirror, Mirror](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/39.htm)", Kirk orders his crew to scramble their communications in order to **avoid them being intercepted by their evil counterparts**;

> **KIRK:** *The intercom may be monitored. Use your communicators for private messages. Subfrequency and scramble.*

- In DS9 : "[Treachery, Faith and the Great River](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Treachery,_Faith_and_the_Great_River_%28episode%29)", Weyoun feels that scrambling will **prevent the Cardassians from determining their location**:

> **WEYOUN:** *Scramble the com frequencies so they can’t lock onto us.*

Comment: Also in Mirror, Mirror Kirk orders his companions to communicate scrambled communications as the primary communication systems may be monitored.

Comment: @Celeritas - Good eyes. I saw it and managed to miss it.

Answer (score -1):

Also season one "The conscience of the King".  Kirk asks communications be scrambled when asking capt John Daley of the astral queen (I think) to allow Kirk to pick up his crew of actors instead of Daley.   I assumed this made the conversation private.  Kirk was scheming at the time.

Comment: But what does scrambling do? You've merely mentioned an example.

Comment: It encrypts communications.  In depth answer is already given above.  By someone else